# What does COUNT(*) do in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT exam_board, COUNT(*)
FROM subjects
GROUP BY exam_board;
```

This is a block of code where 'exam_board' is a field in a table called 'subjects'.

What does each line of code in this block do?

Comment: did you try google? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gives you the count of total number of records fetched in query.

In your specific case, it will give you count of each exam_board group.

```
exam_board  count
A           10
B           29
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Gives you how much records have the same exam_board value for each different exam_board value.

For example, if your table has this data:

```
|exam_board|
 A
 A
 A
 B
 B
```

this query will return:

```
|exam_board |COUNT(*)
 A            3
 B            2
```